# Is there a way to get compiler warnings for missing XML comments in non-public classes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In my project almost all classes are internal (instead of public).

Now I would like to document everything (the classes and their public members). Unfortunately, the compiler warning for missing XML comments seems to include only public classes and their members.

Is there any way to get such a compiler warning for internal classes?

(Using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, C# 4.0)

Comment: Have you considered making each class public, compiling, fixing the errors, then making the class internal again? In other words, I don't have the answer to your question, but this seems a reasonable way to work around the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/releases/view/62209) by Microsoft (hosted on CodePlex).

It is a very nice rule-based tool that integrates into Visual Studio and scans your solution for any styling issues.

One section of its rules is called "Documentation", and refers to all sorts of code styling related to documenting the code.

See rules starting with SA1600